# Keyword Matching in Pyparsing: non-greedy slurping of tokens

Tags: python, parsing, grammar, pyparsing

Pythonistas:

Suppose you want to parse the following string using Pyparsing:

```
'ABC_123_SPEED_X 123'
```

were `ABC_123` is an identifier; `SPEED_X` is a parameter, and `123` is a value. I thought of the following BNF using Pyparsing:

```
Identifier = Word( alphanums + '_' )
Parameter = Keyword('SPEED_X') or Keyword('SPEED_Y') or Keyword('SPEED_Z')
Value = # assume I already have an expression valid for any value
Entry = Identifier + Literal('_') + Parameter + Value
tokens = Entry.parseString('ABC_123_SPEED_X 123')
#Error: pyparsing.ParseException: Expected "_" (at char 16), (line:1, col:17)
```

If I remove the underscore from the middle (and adjust the `Entry` definition accordingly) it parses correctly.

How can I make this parser be a bit lazier and wait until it matches the Keyword (as opposed to slurping the entire string as an Identifier and waiting for the `_`, which does not exist.

Thank you.

*[Note: This is a complete rewrite of my question; I had not realized what the real problem was]*

Comment: I know this much:  you should be using `|`, not `or`, in your assignment of `Parameter`.

Comment: The title of this question should have instead been "Non-greedy matching in pyparsing".

Comment: @gotgenes: done. Made a clearer title.

Comment: @Robert Rossney: In fact, I should be using `^` because I want the longest possible match. Thanks!

Comment: @Arrieta: `^` is unnecessary here, since all 3 options are the same length.

Comment: It is unfortunate that you are using '_' as both a valid identifier character, *and* as a separator between your method and arg names.  See my suggestion to @gotgenes, who is closest to the right track, I would say.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I based my answer off of [this one](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/message/view/HowToUsePyparsing/178079), since what you're trying to do is get a non-greedy match. It seems like this is difficult to make happen in pyparsing, but not impossible with some cleverness and compromise. The following seems to work:

```
from pyparsing import *
Parameter = Literal('SPEED_X') | Literal('SPEED_Y') | Literal('SPEED_Z')
UndParam = Suppress('_') + Parameter
Identifier = SkipTo(UndParam)
Value = Word(nums)
Entry = Identifier + UndParam + Value
```

When we run this from the interactive interpreter, we can see the following:

```
>>> Entry.parseString('ABC_123_SPEED_X 123')
(['ABC_123', 'SPEED_X', '123'], {})
```

Note that this is a compromise; because I use `SkipTo`, the `Identifier` can be full of evil, disgusting characters, not just beautiful `alphanums` with the occasional underscore.

**EDIT:** Thanks to Paul McGuire, we can concoct a truly elegant solution by setting `Identifier` to the following:

```
Identifier = Combine(Word(alphanums) +
        ZeroOrMore('_' + ~Parameter + Word(alphanums)))
```

Let's inspect how this works. First, ignore the outer `Combine`; we'll get to this later. Starting with `Word(alphanums)` we know we'll get the `'ABC'` part of the reference string, `'ABC_123_SPEED_X 123'`. It's important to note that we didn't allow the "word" to contain underscores in this case. We build that separately in to the logic.

Next, we need to capture the `'_123'` part without also sucking in `'_SPEED_X'`. Let's also skip over `ZeroOrMore` at this point and return to it later. We start with the underscore as a `Literal`, but we can shortcut with just `'_'`, which will get us the leading underscore, but not all of `'_123'`. Instictively, we would place another `Word(alphanums)` to capture the rest, but that's exactly what will get us in trouble by consuming all of the remaining `'_123_SPEED_X'`. Instead, we say, "So long as what follows the underscore is *not* the `Parameter`, parse that as part of my `Identifier`. We state that in pyparsing terms as `'_' + ~Parameter + Word(alphanums)`. Since we assume we can have an arbitrary number of underscore + WordButNotParameter repeats, we wrap that expression a `ZeroOrMore` construct. (If you always expect at least underscore + WordButNotParameter following the initial, you can use `OneOrMore`.)

Finally, we need to wrap the initial Word and the special underscore + Word repeats together so that it's understood they are contiguous, not separated by whitespace, so we wrap the whole expression up in a `Combine` construct. This way `'ABC _123_SPEED_X'` will raise a parse error, but `'ABC_123_SPEED_X'` will parse correctly.

Note also that I had to change `Keyword` to `Literal` because the ways of the former are far too subtle and quick to anger. I do not trust `Keyword`s, nor could I get matching with them.

Comment: This may be working ... I am trying to figure out why it works for Parameter declared as a collection of Literals, and will not work if Parameter is declared as a collection of Keywords. Thank you! This may just be the answer!

Comment: It has something to do with the fact that the underscore is in the default `identChars` for `Keyword`. http://crpppc19.epfl.ch/doc/python-pyparsing/htmldoc/pyparsing.pyparsing.Keyword-class.html If you use `Keyword('SPEED_X', identChars=alphanums)` you will get matching. But I would stick with `Literal`.

Comment: Redefine identifier as `Combine(Word(alphanums)+ZeroOrMore('_'+~Parameter+Word(alphanums)))` and I think this will hit the mark.  (BTW, I'm thrilled to see more pyparsing users pitching in on these SO questions!)

Comment: Thanks for that solution, Paul. I couldn't figure out the right way to put the parts together this morning. Your solution is very elegant so I added it to the answer and explained it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that the identifier never ends with an underscore, you can enforce it in the definition:

```
from pyparsing import *

my_string = 'ABC_123_SPEED_X 123'

Identifier = Combine(Word(alphanums) + Literal('_') + Word(alphanums))
Parameter = Literal('SPEED_X') | Literal('SPEED_Y') | Literal('SPEED_Z')
Value = Word(nums)
Entry = Identifier + Literal('_').suppress() + Parameter  + Value
tokens = Entry.parseString(my_string)

print tokens # prints: ['ABC_123', 'SPEED_X', '123']
```

If it's not the case but if the identifier length is fixed you can define Identifier like this:

```
Identifier = Word( alphanums + '_' , exact=7)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this alternative will not work if the Identifier has more than two components. For instance. It break for my_string='ABC_123_Hola_SPEED_X 123'.

Comment: Very close, Identifier just needs a little more tolerance for multiple components, plus the negative lookahead `~Parameter` to avoid accidentally reading the parameter as part of the Identifier.

Answer (score 1):

You can also parse the identifier and parameter as one token, and split them in a parse action:

```
from pyparsing import *
import re

def split_ident_and_param(tokens):
    mo = re.match(r"^(.*?_.*?)_(.*?_.*?)$", tokens[0])
    return [mo.group(1), mo.group(2)]

ident_and_param = Word(alphanums + "_").setParseAction(split_ident_and_param)
value = Word(nums)
entry = ident_and_param + value

print entry.parseString("APC_123_SPEED_X 123")
```

The example above assumes that the identifiers and parameters always have the format XXX_YYY  (containing one single underscore).

If this is not the case, you need to adjust the `split_ident_and_param()` method.

Comment: +1 for using a parse action. Unfortunately, the OP posted only one flavor of Identifier, and we learn in a later post that there might be *more* than 2 underscore-separated components.  I suspect it is also as likely that some identifiers will have only a single component, so the parser really has to take care with those underscores.  Such is often the way with parsing questions, the example data is often a very small and special subset of the larger set of possible and likely inputs.

Answer (score -1):

This answers a question that you probably have also asked yourself:  "What's a real-world application for `reduce`?):

```
>>> keys = ['CAT', 'DOG', 'HORSE', 'DEER', 'RHINOCEROS']
>>> p = reduce(lambda x, y: x | y, [Keyword(x) for x in keys])
>>> p
{{{{"CAT" | "DOG"} | "HORSE"} | "DEER"} | "RHINOCEROS"}
```

**Edit:**

This was a pretty good answer to the original question.  I'll have to work on the new one.

**Further edit:**

I'm pretty sure you can't do what you're trying to do.  The parser that `pyparsing` creates doesn't do lookahead.  So if you tell it to match `Word(alphanums + '_')`, it's going to keep matching characters until it finds one that's not a letter, number, or underscore.

Comment: Albeit slow (I have a huge file), Pyparsing was able to accomplish the desired task.

Comment: Pyparsing has 2 flavors of lookahead, the NotAny class (abbreviated using the `~` operator) for negative lookahead, and the FollowedBy class (no operator shortcut - we have to draw the line somewhere, or we might as well be writing Perl) for an assertive lookahead.  But you are correct to the extent that pyparsing does *not* implicitly look ahead in its grammar for "the next match", you have to code it in yourself using one of these constructs.

Comment: Also, this chaining of several literals can be done in one of several ways: `Or(map(Keyword, "RED GRN BLUE".split()))` or `oneOf("RED GRN BLUE")`.  oneOf is actually preferred here, as it has the smarts built in to be able to tell the difference between a lone ">" and the leading character of ">=".

Comment: Coming in *real* late here, but `FollowedBy` can be represented as `~~` (see Ford's original paper on PEGs: positive lookahead is logically negative lookahead of a negative lookahead and the `&` operator in PEG syntax is merely syntactic sugar).